# Save username and password using Preferences

Tags: android, autocomplete, preferences

I'm having a trouble in using Preferences to save data login in my app. I already saved username and password at the first time but the next time i dont know how to save make autofill/autocomplete password after filled field username. Can anybody help me. Thanx so much.

Answer (score 7):

Try this code this will helps you :)

```
// Get SharedPreferences

 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

// set UI

  EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
  EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

// get value from existing preference


 strusername = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
 strpassword = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");

// set existing value
username.setText(strusername);
password.setText(strpassword);

findViewById(R.id.login).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            // put value in preference on button click
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: tks your code. but it's not what i want. Following your code, editor just saved at the first time. After i sign in other account and also using this code and i again sign in the account as the first time, i'll have to fill all username and password. what i need, i only have to fill field username and password will autofill/autocomplete when they already saved before. u know what i mean. although, i'm sorry when i wrote clearly meaning in my topic.

Comment: Ok but i am sorry to say it is not possible in SharedPreferences, you required to use Database because sharedprefrence handles only one key value which overwrite everytimes.

Comment: For example refer this link for your solution https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database.html